# Perl SQL file write delayed

Tags: sql, perl, fetch

Here is the simple perl script fetching data from SQL.
Read data and write on a file OUTFILE, and print the data on screen for every 10000th line.

One thing I am curious is that the printing the data on screen terminates very quickly(in 30 seconds), however, data fetching and writing on a file ends very slowly(30 minutes later).

The amount of data is not large. The output files size is less than 100Mbyte.

```
while ( my ($a,$b) = $curSqlEid->fetchrow_array() ) 
{
    printf OUTFILE ("%s,%d\n", $a,$b);
    $counter ++;
    if($counter % 10000 == 0){
        printf ("%s,%d\n", $a,$b);
    }
}  
$curSqlEid->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
close(OUTFILE);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you get information on the screen before it's written to the file? Because that certainly doesn't make sense. But otherwise, writing files can be slow, especially if your mysql database is on the same file system you could be reading and writing at the same time for every record.

Comment: Yes, after screen shows everything (print every 10000th lines of the result), I have to wait 30 minites to get the output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering.

Handles other than STDERR are buffered by default, and most handles use a block buffering. That means Perl will wait until there is 8KB* of data to write before sending anything to the system.

STDOUT is special. When is attached to a terminal (and only then), it uses a different kind of buffering: line buffering. When using line buffering, the data is flushed every time a newline is encountered in the data to write.

You can see this by running

```
$ perl -e'print "abc"; print "def"; sleep 5; print "\n"; sleep 5;'
[ 5 seconds pass ]
abcdef
[ 5 seconds pass ]

$ perl -e'print "abc"; print "def"; sleep 5; print "\n"; sleep 5;' | cat
[ 10 seconds pass ]
abcdef
```

The solution is to turn off buffering.

```
use IO::Handle qw( );  # Not needed on Perl 5.14 or later
OUTFILE->autoflush(1);
```

* — 8KB is the default. It can be [configured when Perl is compiled](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#Configuration-and-Compilation). It used to be a non-configurable 4KB until 5.14.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you teach me the location where I should put the "OUTFILE->autoflush(1);"?

Comment: When you want to disable buffering for that handle. Of course, the handle needs to have been created, so it has to be after the `open`.

Comment: This does not work. open(OUTFILE, ">xxx.csv");  
OUTFILE->autoflush(1);
While~~~~

Comment: Then you have another problem on top of the buffering problem, probably something outside of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing the output file size as 0 while the script is running and displaying on the console. Do not go by that. The file size will show up only once the script has finished. This is due to output buffering.

Anyways, the delay cannot be as large as 30 min. Once the script is done, you should see the output file data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various things, but the final conclusion is that python and perl has basically different handling data flow from DB. It looks like in perl, it is possible to handle data line by line while the data is transferred from DB. However, in Python it needs to wait until the entire data download from the server to process it.